# Can't insert ajax data with php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this jquery script

```
<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#id1").val(); 
  var last_name = $("#id2").val();
  var dataString = 'name='+name+'&last_name='+last_name;
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    data:dataString,
    url:'php/insert.php',
    success:function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

and this insert.php script

```
<?php
  $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=kinoseansy user=postgres password=postgrespass")
        or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
  $result = pg_query($dbconn, "INSERT INTO contacts(address,phone_number,city,others) 
                  VALUES('+1 123 456 7890', 'John', 'Doe','123');");
  var_dump($result);
  pg_close($dbconn);
?>
```

but when I try to click button with id=btn1 nothing happens, no errors, no messages in Chrome console and no data inserted in the database. What is wrong here?

edit#1: this is head part of my document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Car Repair | Locations</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $("#btn1").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var name = $("#id1").val(); 
  var last_name = $("#id2").val();
 var dataString = {'name=':name, 'last_name': last_name};
$.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  data:dataString,
  url:'php/insert.php',
  success:function(data) {
    alert(data);
  }
});
});
</script>
```

so jquery library is loaded here, I believe.

Comment: 1) is the script executing after the button exists `$(function() { script here });` 2) did you load jQuery library? 3) Any errors in the console? 4) does the php get called correctly? (network tab in same console)

Comment: Check **Network Tab** of Developer console if you are using chrome, and see ajax process

Comment: please insert your html code. make sure you include jquery library

Comment: PHP needs to run on a web server. Ajax needs to load from a web server. You cannot use file:///c:.....

Answer (score 0):

In your case (note the & as a separator):

```
'name='+name+'&last_name='+last_name
```

But jQuery does that for you if you specify your data as an object:

```
data: { name: name, last_name: last_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind the `click` event in the doc ready block:

```
$(function() { // <----doc ready starts
  $("#btn1").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("#id1").val();
    var last_name = $("#id2").val();
    var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&last_name=' + last_name;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: dataString,
      url: 'php/insert.php',
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
}); // <-----doc ready ends
```

---

Issue seems to me is that you are binding an event to the element before DOM is ready as you have put your script tags.

So instead you should wrap that with `doc ready` block.

---

### Note:

*Make sure you don't have any duplicate ids, what i meant is same ids for multiple elements in a single page.*  So `#btn1` length of the element should be only one *1*.

Comment: I added this function but now I'm getting this error               `XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:(my path)/php/insert.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.jquery-1.7.min.js:4 f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.7.min.js:4 f.extend.ajaxlocations.html:18 (anonymous function)jquery-1.7.min.js:3 f.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.min.js:3 f.event.add.h.handle.i`

Comment: of course, all id's are unique in my doc. Maybe something is wrong here:        `<div class="btns"><a href="#" class="button" id="btn1">Send</a></div>`

Comment: @AndreySaleba what is `(my path)`? Is it some kind of baseurl like `http://example.com/`?

Comment: it's a local path like `C:/Users/AndreyK/Desktop/cr/php/insert.php`

Comment: So the php is not running on a web server? then you cannot do it

Comment: @AndreySaleba you need to setup a local webserver to test php that is causing..as the file path is showing `Desktop`. You can try with wamp, lampp, xampp.

Comment: @Jai thanks, it works fine now with wamp, appreciate your help.